# Overwrite image size of rss feed entry

Tags: html, css, rss

Image is coming with rss feed, How I can force to display image with my custom size?

```
<div id="entry_id=1" class="feed_entry read_entry">
  <h3>
    <p class="feedreader_subtitle">
      <p></p>
    <div class="field field-teaser">
      <p>Description text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-main-imd">
      <a class="imagecache imagecache-s imagecache-linked imagecache-s_linked" href="http://www.wiatrak.nl/32720/droga-sw-jakuba-do-santiago-de-compostela-ii">
    <img class="imagecache imagecache-s" width="115" height="115" title="Sw. Jakub" src="http://url_to_image_com/sites/default/files/imagecache/s/images/story/2014/02/12/swjakub00.jpg" alt="Sw. Jakub">
      </a>
    </div>
      <p></p>
</div>
```

The following is not working

```
 img {width:100px; float:left; border:0; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:7px; margin-right:7px;}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/nitishdhar/yB92P/

There are some classes also defined in the img tag, are you using some other CSS file also which might be having definitions for the image size. To be sure try using a more specific selector to override the size eg-

```
img.imagecache.imagecache-s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nitishdhar/yB92P/1/